# Problema com acesso a arquivo

Tags: apache, permissões

Estou com um problema sério de segurança e realmente não sei como resolver.
Tenho algumas pastas com orçamentos dos setores no mesmo servidor que roda o sistema de intranet que temos. Setei pasta por pasta o usuário do AD que deveria ter acesso. Só que acontece o seguinte, se o usuário for no executar e entrar na pasta geral (Orçamentos) se ele não tem permissão enxerga ela vazia, mas se ele for pela intranet, e clicar no link, ele consegue abrir o arquivo. No servidor setei a permissão para os Administradores locais, só assim o Wamp aceitou abrir os arquivos, mas ai liberou geral.

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que posso fazer? São 57 pastas....

Comment: É porque o Apache roda como Administrador e por isto ele enxerga a pasta. O seu problema me parece com as permissões de pasta do Windows para o seu usuário (pelo que entendi você está usando o apache no Windows). Pode ser também que as pastas estejam apenas ocultas.

Comment: Ai que está o problema, se eu for via explorer ate as pastas as permissões funcionam normalmente. Existe alguma forma do apache enxergar as permissões?

Comment: Acho que então eu não entendi o que você disse, ou talvez você não tenha entendido o que eu disse. Até aonde entendi pelo webserver (apache) as pastas aparecem, mas pelo `explorer` não aparecem, estou certo?

Comment: è isso mesmo, o apache dá acesso total, ignora completamente o que setei de permissoes nas pastas.

Comment: Diego, pastas do "Windows" não tem permissões igual aos sistemas like-unix, a questão é que a pasta só tem acesso para usuários "elevados", quando você executa o Apache ele roda com privilégios de Administrador e por isto ele tem acesso "total". Você quer que usuários locais (do computador) acessem ou que outros computadores acessem, por exemplo `\\PC-1\minha-pasta-compartilhada`?